# Serve dynamically generated file instead of htm

Tags: python, web, twisted

I'm completely new to twisted and need a little push forward. I'm looking for a way to serve a dynamically generated file other than htm page - for example csv file.

EDIT:
It happened that while change of 'content-type' would suffice with csv file, what I needed was a change of 'content-disposition' of request:

```
request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders('content-disposition', ['attachment; filename="file.csv"'])
```

Comment: I have never used twisted. But you should try simply changing the extension of the generated file from `.html` to what you need. These are all text-based files and they tend to convert easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set proper `Content-type` header.

```
request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders('content-type', ['text/csv'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea how to do this is to generate HTTP response like this:

```
...
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8

1,2,3,4
...
```

I don't know whether you are familiar how does raw HTTP request look, but it consists of two major fields:

- header
- body (html)

And they are separated by `\r\n\r\n`. So you just have to send new [`Content-Type` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) (set to `text/csv`) and then binary content instead of HTML.

In twisted it's apparently possible trough [`setHeader`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html#setHeader) method.

#### Edit - additional HTTP info based on comment

You could take look at:

- [HTTP architecture explained](http://devhub.fm/http-requestresponse-basics/)
- some [HTTP request/response examples](http://www.opencalais.com/HTTPexamples)
- supported [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm green to web development, so every bit of explanation helps a lot.

Comment: @demicanadian since it appears you want to learn, I've added few links that may come in handy for general understanding of HTML